# Disable "set +o history" in BASH

Tags: linux, bash, security

I'm trying to secure my users' `.bash_history` file basically following this [article](http://www.pc-freak.net/blog/how-to-make-sure-your-linux-system-users-wont-hide-or-delete-their-bash_history-securing-bash_history-file/) along with some other tricks. The goal is to be able to keep a record of malicious behavior. However, a user can simply do `set +o history` to disable the command history feature. Is there a way to disallow them from disabling it like this?

Comment: Don’t let them use bash.

Comment: If your users are skilled enough to run malicious software they will know how to circumvent this. The bash history is not an audit system, it is a help to the user.